# Can't sort list

Tags: list, sorting, coordinates, common-lisp

I'm trying to use the function `orderlistofcoordinates` to sort a list of coordinates such as  `((3 15) (4 15) (5 15) (3 16) (4 16) (5 16))`

The function definition is as follows:

```
(defun orderlistofcoordinates (coordlist)
  ;; order list of coordinates
  (stable-sort (copy-alist coordlist)
               #'(lambda (x y)
                   (> (+ (* (car x) 10)
                         (second x))
                      (+ (* (car y) 10)
                         (second y))))))
```

I understand what the function is doing, but how can I assign a variable a list of coordinates and then sort it using the function?

I'm having a hard time getting into Lisp, coming from a C background.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`SORT, STABLE-SORT`](https://www.google.fr/search?q=clhs+stable-sort&oq=clhs+stable-sort&aqs=chrome..69i57.2486j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)  have the following signature:

```
sequence predicate &key key => sorted-sequence
```

The return value is the sorted sequence. However, the sort functions are allowed by the language specification to modify the sequence given in input, which might have bad consequences if the original data is referenced by another part of the code (but is totally fine for temporary lists). 
That's why, in order to be always safe, your function first allocates a fresh list by making a copy.

Unlike languages where functions can take references to variables outside of their scope, you cannot modify a *lexical binding* that is not reachable from inside a function in Common Lisp (you can with dynamic binding, i.e. special variables). To clarify, a local function can modify bindings like so:

```
(let ((x 1)) (lambda () (setf x (* x 2))))
```

... but it cannot modify a binding it cannot *see*, like for example reference variables do in C++:

```
void mutate(int &y)
{
    y = y * 2;
}

void test()
{
    int y = 1;
    mutate(y);
    /* now y equals 2 */
}
```

In CL you let the caller be responsible for managing its own bindings and let functions simply return values. You can still write a macro to hide that step from the user, which takes a *place* and modifies it implicitly via [`SETF`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_setf_.htm). A quick and dirty macro might be for example:

```
(defmacro sortf (sequence &rest args)
  `(setf ,sequence (sort ,sequence ,@args))
```

But I wouldn't write a macro for such a simple case. Besides, a robust macro would need to check inputs, provide documentation and possibly signal error messages.

Here is a rewrite of your function which takes advantage of the `:key` argument of `sort`:

```
(defun sort-coordinates (coordinates)
  (stable-sort (copy-alist coordinates)
               #'>
               :key (lambda (point) 
                      (+ (* (first point) 10) (second point)))))
```

Note that I changed names, used dashes to separate words and wrote `first`  instead of `car`.

Comment: Thank you, these minor differences are what's making it hard for me to get into LISP.

Answer (score 2):

The problem may be that you think the list you are passing will be modified, when instead the function is returning a new list with the same co-ordinates but in sorted order.  So if you wish to assign that value to a variable, you'd need to get the new value by calling this function, and then assigning the result back to that variable.

Comment: So, to be explicit, assign your original list to a variable:

`(setf original '((3 15) (4 15) (5 15) (3 16) (4 16) (5 16)))`

Then assign your new list to the result of the function:

`(setf new (orderlistofcoordinates original))`

Then `new` contains the sorted list.  Sorted from high to low values, as it happens.  Was that intentional?

Comment: @EvansWinner: Why are you asking me?

Comment: Thank you Scott and @EvansWinner, I really did think the list I was passing would be modified, instead of a copy.